# No module named 'line_profiler._line_profiler' when calling line_profiler

Tags: python-3.x, line-profiler

I intended to test my code with line_profiler in the following way in Pycharm but got an error just like the title said. I tried in both miniconda 3.8 and python 3.7 (Windows) but got the same error and I don't know how to fix that. I visited the github page where the source code lies and also tried to run my python file as a script. In the end, all attempts failed because of this error. It seems like a bug but I found everything is Okay in Colab. Can anyone give me any advice? Feel free to leave comments and I will appreciate that.

```
    lp = LineProfiler()
    lp_wrapper = lp(Solution) # Solution is the name of self-defined function
    lp_wrapper()
    lp.print_stats()
```

Comment: I believe it's related to the latest update, I opened an issue on github https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler/issues/50

Comment: @Mykhailo All right, thanks a lot!